# Django ForeignKey prevent creation when parent is a child

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
```

I can create new posts like this:

```
post_1 = PostModel.objects.create()
```

Or new posts with a parent post:

```
post_2 = PostModel.objects.create(post=post_1)
```

I want to know if it's possible for a post to have only a parent which itself doesn't have a parent.
So the following wouldn't be allowed:

```
post_3 = PostModel.objects.create(post=post_2) # post_2 has a parent, prevent creation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `.save()` method

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

class PostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')

    def save(self):
        if post and post.post_id:
            raise IntegrityError
        return super().save()
```